# Anchor tag - could not navigate to link in a new tab via 'Open Link in New Tab' option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, reactjs, url

Issue: User right-clicks and opens the navigation action link using the 'Open Link in New Tab' option then it takes an absolute path with # sufficed instead of a window.open URL path.

Example: 'Open Link in New Tab' open this http://localhost:4020/# URL instead of https://www.google.com/

```
<a href="#" onClick={onNavigationAction}>View more</a>

const onNavigationAction = () => {
  window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You've called a function incorrectly.

Call your function like:

```
 <a href="#" onClick=onNavigationAction()>View more</a>
```

```js
const onNavigationAction = () => {
  window.open('https://www.google.com/', '_blank');
};
```

```html
<a href="#" onClick=onNavigationAction()>View more</a>
```

Here is a working [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/shree/s31gbdko/), as Stack Overflow snippets block external URLs from navigating.